# Position child form in TableLayoutPanel(vb.net)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, tablelayoutpanel

I have multiple TableLayoutPanels in the MDI form. Controls are docked in each cell as required size of cells.

However, I have single (TableLayoutPanel3) in which I want to position the child forms(docked to fill). Whenever the buttons (with icons) from TLP1 are clicked, the childforms open and position in TLP3.

Can anyone suggest?

[image]

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution?

Comment: No sam, i just solved my problem for now by creating User controls.. i couldn't place a form in particular TLP

Comment: Yes, that's the way as I suggested in my solution. you cannot place a child form within a TLP. Please mark my response as the answer if that helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create all controls in your child form as a user control. Then you can easily load them in a `TableLayoutPanel`. Otherwise you can't load child forms in a TLP.

Comment: Thank you sam, it was a turnaround to approximate solution